How to prove that the feasible set of a two-asset portfolio is a hyperbola?
The question comes from ‘Mathematics for Finance: An Introduction to Financial Engineering’ by Marek Capiński (Author), Tomasz Zastawniak. The book does not give a complete proof, and I did not find a detailed proof online. But I think this issue is still very important. So posted the question on the stackexchange.
Assume that $-1<\rho_{12}<1$ ， and  $\mu_1\neq\mu_2$ Then for each asset portfolio V in the feasible set,Prove
$x=\sigma_{v}$ and $y=\mu_{v}$ satisfy the hyperbolic equation $$x^2-A^2(y-\mu_0)^2=\sigma_0^2$$ $$A^2=\frac{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2c_{12}}{\left(\mu_1-\mu_2\right)^2}>0$$The two asymptotes of this hyperbola are $$y=\mu_0\pm\frac1Ax$$

Background Information：
Then $\sigma_v^2$ as a function of s reaches the minimum value at the following point $s_0$
$$s_0=\frac{\sigma_2^2-c_{12}}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2c_{12}}$$
Because$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(\sigma_V^2)}{\mathrm{d}s}=2s(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2c_{12})-2(\sigma_2^2-c_{12})=0$$
Where$$\mu_0=\frac{\mu_1\sigma_2^2+\mu_2\sigma_1^2-(\mu_1+\mu_2)c_{12}}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2c_{12}}$$$$\sigma_0^2=\frac{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2-c_{12}}{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2c_{12}}$$ $\sigma_1$ is the standard deviation of asset 1’s rate of return
$\sigma_2$ is the standard deviation of asset 2’s rate of return
$\mu_1$ is the expected return on asset 1
$\mu_2$ is the expected return on asset 2
$c_{12}$ is the covariance of the returns on Asset 1 and Asset 2
expected value of portfolio v:$\\;\mu_v=s\mu_1+(1-s)\mu_2$
Variance of portfolio v:$\\;\sigma_v^2=s^2\sigma_1^2+(1-s)^2\sigma_2^2+2s(1-s)c_{12}\\$   Formula 3.9
The book gives simple proof tips：Substituting $s=\frac{\mu_V-\mu_2}{\mu_1-\mu_2}$ into Equation 3.9.Using simple (or can be considered slightly cumbersome) transformations, we can prove that the proposition is true
geogebra diagram

As written, the formulas don't yield the desired relation. I believe that: (1) in the defn of $\sigma_0^2$, the $c_{12}$ in the numerator should be $c_{12}^2$; and (2) in the defn of $\sigma_v^2$, the coeff of $\sigma_2^2$ should be $(1-s)^2$. Change (1) is consistent with the "dimensional" equivalence of $c_{12}$, $\sigma_1^2$, $\sigma_2^2$; and (2) balances the coeffs $s^2$ and $2s(1-s)$. With those changes, the relation holds. ... Be that as it may: Are you just asking the reader to do the simple/cumbersome transformations for you? Have you tried them yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Thank you for your comment. (2)I have corrected the mistake. But (1), I'm not sure the error exists. I tried substituting $S_0$ into equation for $σ_v^2$. But I can't simplify the equation! Can you share how you simplified this equation?

I'm confident that change (1) is needed. .... I see two ways to proceed: You could follow the substitution tip (and $\sigma_v^2\to x^2$ and $\mu_v\to y$), "complete the square" with the resulting $y^2$ and $y$ terms, then rearrange appropriately to derive the hyperbolic relation. Alternatively, to merely verify that relation, substitute $x^2\to\sigma_v^2$ and $y\to\mu_v$, and then the expressions for $\sigma_v^2$, $\mu_v$, $A^2$, $\sigma_0^2$, $\mu_0$, then simplify like mad until you get to $0=0$. Both ways are tedious, but watching all the terms cancel in the latter can be satisfying. :)

BTW: To go the verification route, write the relation as $$\sigma_v^2-\sigma_0^2 = A^2(\mu_v-\mu_0)^2$$ Then, work on the left-hand and right-hand sides separately, showing that each reduces to $$\frac{(\sigma_2^2 - c_{12} - s p)^2}{p}$$ where $p:=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2c_{12}$.

In the interest of unnecessary re-symbolification, I'll define
$$p_i := \sigma_i^2-c_{12}$$
and to save typing, I'll use $m$ for $\mu$. Then we have
$$\begin{align}
p_0 &= \frac{p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2} & m_0 &= \frac{m_1p_2+m_2p_1}{p_1+p_2} & A^2 &= \frac{p_1+p_2}{(m_1-m_2)^2}\\[6pt]
p_v &= p_1s^2+p_2(1-s)^2 & m_v &= m_1s+m_2(1-s)
\end{align}$$
(Note: The first of these assumes that, in the definition of $\sigma_0^2$, the numerator's $c_{12}$ should be $c_{12}^2$.)
Then, verifying that $(x,y)=(\sigma_v,m_v)$ satisfies the given hyperbolic relation is the same as showing
$$\sigma_v^2-\sigma_0^2 = A^2 (m_v-m_0)^2 \qquad\text{that is,}\qquad p_v-p_0 = A^2(m_v-m_0)^2 \tag{$\star$}$$
Without too much trouble, we find that
$$\begin{align}
p_v - p_0 &= \frac{p_1^2s^2+p_2^2(1-s)^2+p_1p_2s^2+p_1p_2(1-s)^2-p_1p_2}{p_1+p_2} \\[6pt]
&=\frac{p_1s^2+p_2^2(1-s)^2-2p_1p_2s(1-s)}{p_1+p_2} \\[6pt]
&=\frac{\left(\,p_1s-p_2(1-s)\,\right)^2}{p_1+p_2} \\[12pt]
m_v-m_0 &=\frac{(m_1s+m_2(1-s))(p_1+p_2)-(m_1p_2+m_2p_1)}{p_1+p_2} \\[6pt]
&=\frac{(m_1-m_2)\,\left(\,p_1s-p_2(1-s)\,\right)}{p_1+p_2} \\[12pt]
A^2(m_v-m_0)^2 &=\frac{\left(\,p_1s-p_2(1-s)\,\right)^2}{p_1+p_2}
\end{align}$$
which implies $(\star)$. $\square$

If we didn't already know relation $(\star)$ we could derive it by eliminating $s$ from the relations involving $m_v$ and $p_v$. As per the question's "tip", we solve for $s$ in the former ---getting $s = \dfrac{m_v-m_2}{m_1-m_2} $--- and substitute it into the latter. This gives
$$\begin{align}
p_v &= \frac{1}{(m_1-m_2)^2}\left(\;p_1(m_v-m_2)^2 + p_2(m_1-m_v)^2 \;\right)  \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{(m_1-m_2)^2}\left(\;m_v^2(p_1+p_2) - 2 m_v (p_1m_2+p_2 m_1)+p_1m_2^2+p_2 m_1^2\;\right) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{(m_1-m_2)^2}\left(\;
(p_1+p_2)\left( m_v^2 - 2 m_v m_0 \right)
+p_1m_2^2+p_2 m_1^2
\;\right) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{(m_1-m_2)^2}\left(\;
(p_1+p_2)\left( m_v^2 - 2 m_v m_0 +m_0^2\right)
+p_1m_2^2+p_2 m_1^2 - m_0^2(p_1+p_2)
\;\right) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{(m_1-m_2)^2}\left(\;
(p_1+p_2)(m_v-m_0)^2 + (m_1 - m_2)^2 p_0
\;\right) \\[12pt]
p_v-p_0 &= A^2 (m_v-m_0)^2
\end{align}$$
as expected. $\square$
